# PowerDesigner - Access BusinessRules of Model

Tags: c#, powerdesigner

How I can iterate in C# over the BusinessRules of a powerdesigner model?
This does not work:

```
private static void importModelPackages(PdCDM.Model pdModel){
        foreach (PdCDM.ObjectCol curPDBusinessRule in pdModel.BusinessRules){ /*...*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (PdCommon.BusinessRule curPDBusinessRule in pdModel.BusinessRules) {
   /*...*/ 
}
```

Another possibility:

```
PdPDM.ObjectCol col = pdModel.BusinessRules;
foreach (PdCommon.BusinessRule rul in col) {
   /*...*/ 
}
```

Comment: The API is described in a .chm file, which is in PowerDesigner installation directory. Mine is named pdvbs16.chm.